# Use Alternate Credentials - How to use Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I have set up a SQL Server database in Azure and added an Azure AD group with a few members.

When I connect with SSMS using my Azure AD account, this works fine. But when i use the same credentials under User Alternate Credentials in Power BI desktop, it fails to connect: Could not authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again.

I log on using @.com with the correct password and the server and database selected in the drop-down box.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the PowerBI desktop doesn't support to connect the Azure SQL database using the Azure AD account. Please refer this thread for the [similar question](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/Connect-to-Azure-SQL-Database-Using-Active-Directory-User/td-p/19327).

If you want to support this feature you may vote the feature from [this link](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/10172688-sql-azure-connector-with-azure-ad-auth).

Comment: Thanks, it see it is not support.

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/10172688-sql-azure-connector-with-azure-ad-auth

Workaround: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/04/06/connect-from-power-bi-to-azure-sql-database-using-aad-authentication/